# How can I search patterns with regex groups of characters that have the first two letters uppercased?

Tags: regex, webclient, system.net

I am trying to scrap using system.net and regular expressions a web page that looks like in the picture in order to get info like Created By: [see the picture!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G42KQ.png)

Here is my code so far:

```
String html = web.DownloadString("https://..");
            MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, @"<div>\s*(.+?)\s*</div>", RegexOptions.Singleline);

            foreach (Match m in m1)
            {
                string tarif = m.Groups[1].Value;
                tarife.Add(tarif);
```

When I tried to inspect the element in Chrome it looks something like this:

[inspect element from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVx9q.png)

How can i use regex to extract the name, anyone who can advise me?

Comment: Name of what ? there is no name on your posted image.

Comment: Underneath Created by field there is TDascultu. This is an abreviation like Jessika Parker is JParker

Comment: Razvan,Update your answer, copy html text which you want to parse and state what you want get out of that html. That way it way easy to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like that?

```
var str = "dsGHsal TDascultu sdOfsaf JParker OFHlsdjfls"
var re = /\b[A-Z]{2}[a-z]+/g
matches = str.match(re)       //["TDascultu", "JParker"]
```

Comment: First of all, sorry in advance for my beginner level. I think it's correct, but i have to scrap this from a html page. The plan is to identify that name and write it to a textbox and i don't seem to know how to include the filter in my syntax.